# Filtering a function in WP

Tags: wordpress

I have a child theme and I am trying to filter the following:

```
// add the function to the init hook
add_action( 'init', 'options_typography_get_google_fonts' );

// add a font to the $google_fonts variable
function options_typography_get_google_fonts() {

    // Google Font Defaults
    global $google_faces;
    $google_faces = array(

        'Great Vibes, cursive' => '*Great Vibes'    
        );

    return $google_faces;

}
```

What is the best way to filter this so I can add more google fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so here are some options:

(1) If the parent theme checks if the `options_typography_get_google_fonts` function exists (with `function_exists`) you can override the function by redeclaring it in your child theme.

(2) If the parent theme does not, you should be able to remove the action in your childtheme:

`remove_action( 'init', 'options_typography_get_google_fonts' );`

and build your own (similar but extended) function based on the function you just removed.

(3) If you're building a child theme, and would like users to be able to filter the list of fonts, you should return a filterable array:

`return apply_filters( 'my_options_typography_get_google_fonts_filter', $google_faces );`